# Laravel Migrations that cause error don't rollback

Tags: database, laravel-4

I've found that, while building up my database schema in Laravel, that failed migrations don't rollback, which kind of makes migrations pointless.

For example, I have this migration:

```
Schema::create('accounts', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('act_id');

    $table->string('act_name', 50)->unique();
    $table->boolean('act_active')->default(1);
    $table->unsignedInteger('act_type');
    $table->unsignedInteger('act_businesstype')->default(1);

    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('accounts', function($table)
{
    $table->foreign('act_businesstype')->references('bst_id')->on('businesstypes');
});
```

Anyway, if I run that migration, the table gets created just fine, but the foreign key fails and I get an error. That's fine. I should get an error. BUT, common sense has me assuming the following:

1. Since the migration failed, the changes should automatically rollback. Well, they don't.

Okay, so

2. I should call migrate:rollback to undo those changes. Well, there is no record of that migration happening so I end up rolling back the one that occurred before.

Am I doing something wrong here? The only way I've figured out how to "undo" a failed migration is to actually go into the database and drop the table. This is extremely frustrating when working on a complex schema where I'm going back and forth fixing errors.

So, I guess now that I've had my little rant, my question is:

**How do I rollback a migration that throws an error?**

Comment: This is an excellent question that should definitely make Laravel developers lose some sleep. So disappointing there is still no working solution after a year.

Comment: Same I always have this problem and I have to go into the database and delete the table manually... Laravel should at least implement it at the first place!

Comment: I usually comment my migration, run it successfully and then do a regular rollback to execute the code within the `down` method of the migration file.

I also use a local database instance to test my migrations and wipe the schema out if I deal with too many changes. Only then do I actually start running my migrations on the real database. But you are correct, there doesn't seem to be any way to do it using the provided tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coming back to this question years later and knowing much more about how databases work now:

There is no way for a migration to "automatically rollback". Schema changes cannot be performed in transactions. Only INSERTS, UPDATES, and DELETES can be rolled back.

In order for this to function correctly, there would need to be an equivalent "drop" script that runs in the event of an error to revert the schema change.

EDIT: It seems like this question still gets some traction, so I wanted to link Larvel's documentation on how to structure a migration file: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#migration-structure, and I'll post the code here for posterity, along with an adjustment on how to handle errors:

```php
<?php
 
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 
return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        try {
            Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('airline');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->down();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('flights');
    }
};
```

So, the `down` function will execute if you choose to manually rollback a migration or an error occurs.

The final thing to note is the use of `Schema::dropIfExists` in the `down` function. For this particular migration, if the `Schema::create` call fails, then no table is created. That means there is no table to drop. `dropIfExists` prevents an additional error in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to execute your migrations from within a transaction, so that if an error occurs mid-migration, nothing gets committed and the whole transaction gets rolled back. Antonio Carlos Ribeiro has written a great class that handles this process neatly; see [his description of the process here](https://antoniocarlosribeiro.com/technology/articles/unbreakable-laravel-migrations) as well as the [finished migration class on GitHub](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/support/blob/master/src/Migration.php).

Once you've installed his class, create your migrations so that they extend the new Migration class, and call `migrateUp()` and `migrateDown()` in place of `up()` and `down()`:

```
class CreateAccountsTable extends PragmaRX\Support\Migration {

    protected function migrateUp()
    ...
```

...and enjoy not having to manually fix a botched migration again!

Comment: I finally got around to trying this solution. I implemented this class and it doesn't seem to do anything. Even if a migrate call generates an error, an tables that were successfully created are left in the database, and the migration is added to the migrations table. So, I have to delete that and all the tables created from the migration to "roll it back".

Answer (score 1):

After 7 years, the same problem still happens to me, I didn't find an official solution, but as this question is relevant and appears in the first position on google, so I go from my solution. Able to solve it as follows: Putting a try/catch in the "up" function and using a "dd" to stop the process before saving the migration to the database.

```php
    public function up()
    {
        try {
            if (!Schema::hasTable('smart_banners_sellers')) {
                Schema::create('smart_banners_sellers', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
                    $table->string('seller_id', 20);
                    $table->bigInteger('smart_banner_id')->unsigned();
    
                    $table->foreign('seller_id')
                        ->references('CodigoVendedor')
                        ->on('vendedores')
                        ->onDelete('Cascade');
    
                    $table->timestamps();
                });
            }
        } catch (Throwable $ex) {
            Schema::dropIfExists('smart_banners_sellers');
            dd("--- ERROR: ". $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I use a "dd" (dump() + die()), because even if it finds an error and enters "catch", the migration will be registered from the "migrations" table, being ignored next time, and that's not what we want because there is an error. What we want is:

- See the error, so I used a "catch",
- Delete the created table because it contains an error, so I used "Schema::dropIfExists"
- Don't register the migration in the db, stop the code execution, that's why I used "dd".